# Blanket redirecting domains with VirtualHosts

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, redirect

I have Apache set up on a CentOS 5 box with some virtual hosts.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/default
  ServerName fail
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/website1.net
  ServerName website1.net
  ServerAlias *.website1.net
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/website2.com
  ServerName website2.com
  ServerAlias *.website2.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Someone set up a CNAME to website2.com, effectively pretending he runs the site.

I was able to redirect it with some more Apache config magic.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName evil.villain.com
  RedirectMatch permanent ^/?(.*) http://website2.com/$1
</VirtualHost>
```

But this technique requires I specify the domain I want to redirect.

Is there a way I can just redirect *all* "evil" CNAME records to my own domain name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache will serve the default vhost for unknown ServerNames. 
Stick this at the top of your vhost config, verify with `apachectl -S`

```
<VirtualHost _default_:*>
  RedirectMatch permanent ^/?(.*) http://website2.com/$1
</VirtualHost>
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html#default

Comment: This works beautifully, thanks! (I've reached my daily vote limit, I'll be sure to upvote it tomorow)