# How to stop answering to certain domains using apache2?

Tags: apache-2.2, domains

I have someone who added my IP address (private server) as an A record to some of his porn domains. Apache is delivering the default page ("It works"), but I try to find a way to not answer the call at all.

Anyone any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your default virtual host to a 403 forbidden response/message:

```
<VirtualHost *>
 ServerName nohost
 ErrorDocument 403 "The website you requested was not found on this server"
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule . - [F]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: And just make sure this default host loads before any of your real virtual hosts.

Answer (score 1):

I once had a similar problem. I solved it using redirects.

Go take a look at [this question I posted](https://serverfault.com/questions/250274/blanket-redirecting-domains-with-virtualhosts)

You could just redirect all requests to a 404 or a blank page.